# Value order not as expected, after performing a BFS on the graph?

Tags: c++, data-structures, graph, breadth-first-search, adjacency-list

I'm trying to create a graph based on adjacency lists. This is the structure of the graph.

```
class Graph{
private:
    struct Vertex
    {
        int data;
        Vertex *next;
        set<int> anti;
    };
    struct Neighbors
    {
        Vertex *head;
    };
public:
    int Limit;
    list<int> print_list;
    Neighbors *adjacent;
    Graph(int Limit);
    Vertex* Add_Vertex(int data);
    void Connect(int before, int data);
    void Display();
    list<int> BFS(int v);
    list<int> DFS(int source);
};
```

The code compiles completely fine, but when I try to replicate the order of creating edges for [LINK](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/breadth-first-search-or-bfs-for-a-graph/) or any other page, I always get a different order.

My question is, what is causing my order to be different from theirs? I think I'm following the logic smoothly but instead of producing 2 0 3 1, I produce 2 3 0 1. As much as possible, I want these outputs to be similar.

---

**Edges & Creation:**

```
Graph::Vertex* Graph::Add_Vertex(int data)
{
    //Initialize vertex
    Vertex* temp = new Vertex;
    temp->data = data;
    temp->next = NULL;
    return temp;
}
void Graph::Connect(int first, int second)
{
    Vertex *temp;
    //Create a vertex and get pointer for second

    if (first != second) {
        //Create a vertex and get a pointer for first
        temp = Add_Vertex(first);
        //Connect created node to second vertex
        temp->next = adjacent[second].head;
        adjacent[second].head = temp;
    }
    temp = Add_Vertex(second); 
    //Connect created node to first vertex
    temp->next = adjacent[first].head; 
    adjacent[first].head = temp;


}
```

**BFS Implementation (Main call not included):**

```
list<int> Graph::BFS(int from) {
    print_list.clear();
    bool *visited = new bool[Limit];
    for (int i = 0; i < Limit; i++)
        visited[i] = false;

    list<int> queue;
    visited[from] = true;
    queue.push_back(from);

    while (!queue.empty())
    {
        from = queue.front();
        print_list.push_back(from);
        queue.pop_front();

        Vertex *Displaying = adjacent[from].head;
        while (Displaying)
        {
            int adjacent_node = Displaying->data;
            if (!visited[adjacent_node])
            {
                visited[adjacent_node] = true;
                queue.push_back(adjacent_node);
            }
            Displaying = Displaying->next;
        }
    }
    return print_list;
}
```

Another test on:

1 2, 2 3, 1 5, 1 4, 4 7, 7 8, 8 9, 2 6, 5 7

Expected:

1 2 4 5 3 6 7 8 9

Actual:

1 4 5 2 7 6 3 8 9

where starting vertex is 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `BFS`, you use a queue to keep track of nodes you need to visit.  You pull the next node from the front, and add new nodes to be visited to the end.

What you want to use instead is a stack - add and remove nodes from the end.  This will change around the order nodes are visited, and change the output you generate.

Alternatively, you can leave the code in `BFS` unchanged, and change `Connect` to add new nodes to the *end* of the Neighbors list, rather than at the beginning.